# setOnItemClick isnt getting recognized(Android)

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I am displaying a Listview of recorded data and when the user clicks on a specific list item, it triggers an intent and brings the user to the profile for that selected user. I worked when i first ran my project but ever since it just will not work. Thank you in advance.

```
public class CowListView extends ListActivity {

    RegisterCowAdapter cowAdapter;
    private DataBaseHelper databaseHelper;
    public ListView listView;
    TextView student_Id;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cow_list_item);
        cowAdapter = new RegisterCowAdapter(this);
        cowAdapter.open();
        updateCowUI();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                student_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cowtagnolist);
                String studentId = student_Id.getText().toString();
                Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CowProfile.class);
                Toast.makeText(CowListView.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                objIndent.putExtra("student_Id", Integer.parseInt(studentId));
                startActivity(objIndent);
            }
        });

    }


    private void updateCowUI() {

        Cursor cursor = cowAdapter.getAllCowData();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{RegisterCowAdapter.COWTAGNO, RegisterCowAdapter.COWDOB};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.cowtagnolist, R.id.cowdoblist};
        SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.cow_list_item,
                cursor,
                from,
                to
        );
        this.setListAdapter(reminders);
    }
}


    private void updateCowUI() {

         Cursor cursor =cowAdapter.getAllCowData();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{RegisterCowAdapter.COWTAGNO, RegisterCowAdapter.COWDOB};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.cowtagnolist, R.id.cowdoblist};
        SimpleCursorAdapter reminders  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.cow_list_item,
                cursor,
                from,
                to
        );
        this.setListAdapter(reminders);
    }
   }
```

**My XML**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:longClickable="true">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        >
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cowtagnolist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"


        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cowdoblist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:textColor="@color/black">

    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should try debugging.

Comment: Why have you enclosed ListView code inside  public void onClick(View view) { ?

Comment: Firstly Move your codes in onClick() function to onCreate() also you must define only single ListView object that is not be in onCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

Might be one of two things.
You have implemented `OnClickListener` but you have not set the ListView to listen to that specific class nor have you called any method in your `onCreate` that will set the ListView's listener to that class.
Secondly I think you might need to implement `OnItemClickListener` and not `onCLickListener` since thats what is on the ListView, an Item.
Im confused though why do you have `onClick` and then you set the listener inside this method? How will it know in the first place that the view has been clicked if it is not listening from the beginning i.e. in the `onCreate` or a method called in the `onCreate` ? Your logic seems abit off

Comment: in short implement OnItemClickListener then set the ListView's onItemClickListener to 'this' in the onCreate.